# Установка на python файлы с расширением .whl и .zip(добавление библиотек)

Tags: python, windows

Не знаю как точно называется(библиотеки вроде).мне нужно установить раcширение на python 3. colorama-0.3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl и snack2210-tcl.zip
Но не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Документацию почитайте...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: это можно написать практически для любого вопроса на SO.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install wheel 

pip install file.whl
```

Comment: На Винде, это возможно вызывается как `py -mpip install`.